# List of Definite/Indefinite Integrals1

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I was wondering if anyone knew of any good lists of definite/indefinite integrals ranging from high school to 1st-2nd Year university level?

Thanks, David

Comment: What about the list on Wikipedia? Or one of the many pages that comes up when you put "definite integral list" into Google?

Comment: I didn't ask if there were lists. I asked for lists that are good. Those that have a good balance of different skill levels, substitution methods, etc.
I (possibly falsely) assumed that Math Stack Exchange would be a good place to find such a list. 

Should I have worded the question differently?

Comment: There is a number of books with very complete lists of integrals and series. For example [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nLg7fTLbXKMvKj5krylCctqwPI9-zRfz/view). Even though it is in russian you may find similar in english. The link points to the first volume of this book (there are also [volume 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xVr7R3KQ7Bh5bbPJUfZ_Hg7K4AfEnS7P/view) and [volume 3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NjLpx2ZN5KDBndL8W7XA9BuaIWp91mOV/view))

Comment: @roman - thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say my comment answers the question I'm putting it here as an answer.

I've seen a number of books with lists of integrals purposed mainly for hands-on engineers. I have not met those books in english but just to give you the idea here are [some (v.1)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nLg7fTLbXKMvKj5krylCctqwPI9-zRfz/view) [examples (v.2)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xVr7R3KQ7Bh5bbPJUfZ_Hg7K4AfEnS7P/view) [of those (v.3)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NjLpx2ZN5KDBndL8W7XA9BuaIWp91mOV/view) in russian. I'm pretty sure there are similar in english out there in a wild.

Hope you will be able to find one for yourself by an affordable price.